# Pagination using PHP and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, pagination

I am trying to use pagination function in my website. the code is given below. But the problem is that it shows All the record But I want to use pagination for that record which is displayed with `$_GET` means I make a link in php some thing like this

```
<a href="page.php?id<?php echo $video_id; ?>">Show</a>
```

but it does not show me record. anyone help me I used the is given below. in *content_displaer.php* I am new here so do not know how to put the code kindly download this [file](http://www.tadreesonline.com/content_displayer.zip) for refference. I am using `$_GET['id']` in *content.php* file and just call the content_displayer by using javascript.

Comment: I add $show_id = $_GET['id']; and use this query SELECT * FROM insert_video where cat_id='$show_id'; but it show error Undefined index at line where I write $show_id = $_GET['id'];

Comment: You sure there is `mypage.php?id=XX`?

Comment: yes I ma using this but without pagination

Comment: You forgot the `=` in the line `href="page.php?id=<?php echo $video_id; ?>"`.